# How to run Console Application from a ASP.NET Application?

Tags: asp.net, console

How can I run a console application (.EXE) from ASP.NET Application.

Both ASP.NET Application & Console application are on the same server and in the same directory but in different folders.

ASP.NET Application is hosted in IIS Server

How can I run the console application from my asp.net web application ?

Sorry for asking the question in an improper way, now I have updated it as per my exact need.

Comment: It throws an error? Hmm... That's weird. I can only be guessing at what kind of error it's throwing. You didn't find it useful to provide that information in your question or you expect us consult our magic crystal balls?

Comment: downvoted because you neglected to post the error message... which almost certainly contains the answer to your question.

Comment: So what does this `WCFServ_UserLog.exe` does? Is it the one that's throwing the error?

Comment: @msbyuva, so why are you posting this in your question? What does this has to do with your problem and the exception you are getting?

Comment: Most probably you have a bug in WCFServ_UserLog.exe? Incorrect config maybe?

Comment: @msbyuva - If the executable is located on the same machine the code is running on, why are you connecting to itself with an IP address?

Comment: Another prime example of an XY problem. You should be asking `Why does my executable throw [ERROR DESCRIPTION] on my server?`, not `How to run Console Application from a ASP.NET Application?`

Comment: I have updated my actual problem in the question, please have a look in to that, any help will be appreciated. –

Comment: Web apps have no console context and are not meant to blindly run exe files. For example, a simple MessageBox.Show would "break" it since the web server can't show you that box on your browser. You will need to take care how you invoke it and that you spawn a process to handle it and any errors/output it generates. If you have existing code, please post it.

Comment: @Nikki9696: var proc = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"D:\Inetpub\SERVICES\UserLog\bin\Debug\UserLog.exe");    // Some Code   //  proc.Kill();

Answer (score 0):

My first guess is that it might be a firewall issue since the remote machine is refusing the connection.  If the code is running on the same server as the executable you want to run, why are you entering an IP address? Try changing the IP to `127.0.0.1` or `LOCALHOST` and see if you get the same error.

Comment: No, it is not about the firewall issue. I have updated my actual problem in the question, please have a look in to that, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I changed the IP to 127.0.0.1 and I get the same problem :(

Comment: Hi ,I Have similar problem .did you find the solution??